# taking too many mib while writing objects in push heroku java

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I need your help for this following issues.

I added postgresql dependency , plugin , procifle for my web apps. Then I built pom ,it's not take too long. But when I tried to push heroku ,

```
Counting objects: 193, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100 % (188/188), done.
Writing objects: 5 % (11/193), 1.09 MiB | 19.00 KiB/s
```

After 8 % , 41 MiB | 80 KiB/s

So, I think that there is a problem why taking too many MiB than others.

Please help me guys!

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that it is taking too long to upload your project to Heroku, correct?

This is because it is your first time pushing your project to Heroku, so the entire Git repository must be copied over (and from the looks of it, you have a very large codebase).

After the first deploy is done, any subsequent deploys will be much faster as you will only need to upload the changes since your previous deployment, which is usually not very large.

Something you can do to reduce your Git repository size, however, is to not store static assets like images, movies, or files in your Git project. Put them into some storage service like S3 and link to them.

Comment: No, there is no large codebase. When I tried to finish 100%, it's really taking too long at 10%. It didn't finish yet :(

Comment: Can you run the command `du -sh <your-heroku-folder>` if you're on Linux, or `du <your-heroku-folder>` if you're on OSX and paste the results here?

Comment: I'm not clear about your command. Is it about disk usage?? But it's not work in my computer. I'm using win8.

Comment: It's all fine now. Your first answer was right. I think that the problem is I'm a beginner for heroku. So, I worried about taking too long time for pushing process. So, thanks a lot for your support @rdegges :)